# How to convert this date format in TSQL: Date(1438315200000-0400) to yyyy-MM-dd?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, converters

I believe this is JSON Date format: Date(1438315200000-0400)

I have records coming in with that format and I need to parse and convert to 
yyyy-MM-dd, in SQL.

Anyone have any advice on this?

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't make sense as a JS value. Don't you *know* what you're using?

Comment: It's doesn't make sense to parse it to yyyy-MM-dd for SQL, either. It implies you're using code somewhere that will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Actual SQL dates are both stored in a binary format and transported that way by the main data access protocols. SQL Server dates aren't human-readable at all, and are only shown in the yyyy-MM-dd format by query tools and debuggers as a convenience.

Comment: These records are inserted as JSON text in the table. yeah I think Unix time.

Comment: That's a problem with the schema, then :( How is the json column first populated?

Comment: Yeah I don't have control over that. Guess I'll have to use ADO in C#.

Comment: Looks like Unix time with a time zone appended on. http://www.epochconverter.com so you can use `dateadd’.

Comment: It's JSON ISO time format.

Comment: "JSON ISO time format" there's no such thing

Comment: There's this: https://skinn3r.wordpress.com/2009/01/26/t-sql-function-to-convert-unix-timestamp-into-ms-sql-datetime/ Then you just need to break up the string into time and offsets, compute the date and then apply the offset.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719876/can-i-serialized-datetime-data-json-in-query-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

using http://www.epochconverter.com/ it looks like that is a Unix timestamp, not json. The epochconverter website also says it's trying to do milliseconds. So, you could knock off the timezone, divide the rest by 1000, and do a dateadd to get the seconds since 1/1/1970. That will give you the datetime in GMT.

```
select dateadd(s, 1438315200000 / 1000, '1/1/1970') 

ConvertedDate
-----------------------
2015-07-31 04:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```